# Select only relevant news items that are linked on a page (multiple one two many relationships)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `page` entity that consists of multiple `container`s. In those containers a user can link a `news list`. Those `news list`s again contain `news items`.

Now, I want to search for `news items` but I need the `page` the `news list` is linked on as well.

I've tried this:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
    SELECT p, c, n, i
    FROM VendorNameBundle:Page p
    LEFT JOIN p.container c
    LEFT JOIN c.news n
    LEFT JOIN n.items i
    WHERE i.title LIKE :title
    GROUP BY i.id
');
```

Which basically works as it gives me the correct page. But to find the correct `news item` I would have to run through all `container`s and their `news list`s. And of course, when I retrieve the items I get all, not just the one important for the search.

How can I solve this in an elegant way?

**Summarized: I need the `news items` and their corresponding `page` entities. How can I solve this in a neat and elegant way?**

**Note**: If a `news list` is listed on multiple pages, one `page` in the result is enough and it's not important which.

**Edit**

Here are the relations as requested in the comments:

**PAGE**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Container", mappedBy="page", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "asc"})
 */
protected $containers;
```

**CONTAINER**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="containers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Page_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $page;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="News", inversedBy="containers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $news;
```

**NEWS**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Container", mappedBy="news")
 */
protected $containers;
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of how your relations are set up in Doctrine?

Comment: Jasper N. Brouwer has the right answer. You have to reverse the order of selection. This is also not just specific to doctrine or symfony, but this is how you should do if you were writing a crude mysql query

Comment: @broncha You say it's a crude MYSQL query. Could you give an example on how to solve this problem in a better way.

Comment: @Khez I've added the relations.

Comment: @Khez what I said was, you would query in these situations as Jasper N. Brouwer even if it were a crude mysql query and not DQL. You are looking for item, then it should be your first selection, and select your way up to page.

Comment: @Broncha Ah, now I get it. I misread your comment. Thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The query

Because you are searching for news items, I suggest you work from those news items up to the pages (in stead of the other way around):

```
SELECT i, n, c, p
FROM VendorNameBundle:Item i
JOIN i.news n
JOIN n.container c
JOIN c.page p
WHERE i.title LIKE :title
```

This query does assume that *every* news item is within a news list, *every* news list is within a container and *every* container is within a page. If this is not true, use a `LEFT JOIN` in stead of a `JOIN`, otherwise you're going to miss some news items.

#### Grouping

This query will give you the data you want, but probably *not* formatted the way you want it. If you want to group the items per page or news list (etc), you'll need to do this manually (in code).

You can however let the query do some ordering, so the grouping (in code) becomes easier. The following example will order the results by first the title of the page, then the title of the news list:

```
SELECT i, n, c, p
FROM VendorNameBundle:Item i
JOIN i.news n
JOIN n.container c
JOIN c.page p
WHERE i.title LIKE :title
ORDER BY p.title ASC, n.title ASC
```

Now grouping can be done like this:

```
$currentPage     = null;
$currentNewsList = null;

foreach ($newsItems as $newsItem) {
    $newsList = $newsItem->getNews();
    $page     = $newsList->getContainer()->getPage();

    if ($page !== $currentPage) {
        $currentPage = $page;
        echo '- ' . $page->getTitle() . "\n";
    }

    if ($newsList !== $currentNewsList) {
        $currentNewsList = $newsList;
        echo '    - ' . $newsList->getTitle() . "\n";
    }

    echo '        - ' . $newsItem->getTitle() . "\n";
}
```

Which will print something like this:

```
- Page A
    - News list A
        - Found news item
    - News list C
        - Another found news item
- Page B
    - News list B
        - Yet another found news item
```

Comment: +1 = +125 ;) Thanks a lot for your help and your effort. Much appreciated and exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just revert the joins to `RIGHT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` and select the `Items` not the `Pages`:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
    SELECT p, c, n, i
    FROM VendorNameBundle:Items i
    JOIN i.news n
    JOIN n.container c
    JOIN c.page p
    WHERE i.title LIKE :title
    GROUP BY i.id
');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could simply search for the `items` you want:

`$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT i FROM Vendor:Item i WHERE i.title LIKE :title");`

Which will give you the collection of specific `items` you want.

Then, on the hydrated `Item` entities the query returns, you should have the methods to run through the relations, something like:

```
$items = $query->getResult();
$pages = array();
foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
  $pages[$index] = $item->getNews()->getContainer()->getPage();
}
```

This assumes that your relations are direct (an item belongs to exactly one list, a list belongs to exactly one container, and a container to exactly one page).
If it is not the case but you don't care which of the pages pops out, you can do:

```
$pages[$index] = $item->getNews()[0]->getContainers()[0]->getPages()[0];
```

The concept here is that, for instance, your `Container` entity has something like this declared:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="containers")
*/
private $page;
//this returns an instance of Page entity
public function getPage() { return $this->page; }
```

And your `Page` entity should have the inverse side of the relation, which we're using here, defined like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Container", mappedBy="page")
*/
private $containers;
//this returns an instance of PersistentCollection which is iterable, can be
// ArrayAccess'd, well, it's a glorified array
public function getContainers() { return $this->containers; }
```

Just a side note here: when you try to access related entities, they probably (depending on your Doctrine's configuration) haven't been loaded, therefore Doctrine will address the DB behind the scenes, so from a performance point of view it can quickly become pretty heavy.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't even think of that before. I already have a bidirectional relationship. But It didn't come to my senses, that I can go the other way, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is having bidirectional relationships between your entities (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) and then, you select the News Items as below:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
    SELECT i
    FROM VendorNameBundle:Items i
    WHERE i.title LIKE :title
    GROUP BY i.id
');
```

In this way, you obtain the news items which you want, and you access to the page via the News List and the Containers. For example:

```
$item->getNewsList()->getContainer()->getPage();
```

and Doctrine hydrates the objects. If the News List is in some pages (as you said in the note of your post), you would need to access to any container and then to the page.

Comment: I didn't even think of that before. I already have a bidirectional relationship. But It didn't come to my senses, that I can go the other way, as well.